# git log --reflog vs git reflog

Tags: git, git-reflog

After playing around with `rm` etc etc, my `git reflog` no longer shows the past commits.

However, `git log --reflog` is still able to show them.

How does `git log --reflog` show dangling commits if it doesn't rely on `git reflog`?

Comment: When you say *my reflog*, how many reflogs are you looking at? Just the one for `HEAD`? Just the one for `master`? All of them?

Comment: @torek, `reflog` is now empty while it used to have quite a number of lines.

Comment: Let me try a different way of phrasing that: How are you viewing the reflog(s)? Specifically, *what commands are you using?* And: **there is more than one reflog.**

Comment: @torek, `git reflog`, output is empty. `git log --reflog` shows the past commits.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Reflogs do not hold commit ancestry: reflogs hold name-update history.  It's the *commit graph* that holds commit ancestry.  `git log` would like some set of starting points, but after getting them, it looks at the commit graph.  `git log --reflog` normally alters the set of starting points, but if you've removed all the reflogs (or never had any, e.g., in a bare clone), it doesn't: you get the standard single starting point, `HEAD`.

Note that reflog entries eventually expire, after 90 days by default,<sup>*</sup> but the *graph* never expires.  A new clone has no reflog history, but has all the graph linkage—and `git log --reflog` still shows multiple commits.

---

<sup>*</sup>The default expiry is 30 days for some entries, 90 for most, and for the special reflog for `refs/stash`, never.  The deetails are out of scope of this answer.

---

#### Long

Experimentally:

```
rm .git/logs/HEAD
```

removes the HEAD reflog, but `git reflog` still shows some data.  On the other hand:

```
rm -r .git/logs
```

removes all reflogs after which `git reflog` shows nothing.

At this point, one might expect `git log --reflog` not to find anything.  However, apparently this uses the same "add `HEAD` itself as a default" behavior.  So now that there are no reflogs, `git log --reflog` does the equivalent of:

```
git log HEAD
```

which shows the current commit and its ancestors.  Using:

```
git log --no-walk --reflog
```

you'll see just the one commit identified by `HEAD`.

This means that the answer to:

> How does `log --reflog` work if it doesn't rely on reflog?

is that it does not do anything that plain `git log` does not do any more:

- When you supply particular starting commits to `git log`, Git shows those commits, and commits reachable from those commits, without using `HEAD` as a starting point.  (Adding `--no-walk` makes this clearer.)
- When you *don't* supply any particular starting commit, `git log` uses `HEAD` as its starting point.  (Again, adding `--no-walk` makes this clearer.)

(When you do have some reflogs—which is the normal case—the `--reflog` argument supplies the reflog values as starting points, which disables the "use `HEAD` as starting point" action.  If everything now makes sense, you can stop here!)

#### A potential source of confusion

It's important, when using Git, to know what a *commit* does for you, vs what a *branch name* like `master`, or a *reflog entry* like `master@{3}`, does for you.

Each Git commit holds a full snapshot of all of your files, but that's not all that it holds.  Each commit also holds some *metadata*.  Much of this metadata—information about the commit—is pretty obvious as it shows up in `git log` output.  This includes the name of whoever made the commit, an email address, and a date-and-time-stamp, along with the log message they provided.

Each commit itself has a unique hash ID, too.  This hash ID is, in essence, the "true name" of the commit.  It's how Git looks up the actual commit object, in its big database of *all commits and other supporting Git objects*.

A branch name like `master` simply holds the hash ID of one particular commit.  This one commit is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.  But a commit, such as the last one in the `master` branch, *also* can hold a commit hash ID.  Each commit, in its metadata, has a list of hash IDs.  These are the *parents* of the commit.

Most commits have just one parent hash ID.  This forms these commits into simple backwards-looking chains.  We can draw such a chain like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

if we use uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs.  Here `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit on `master`.  Commit `H` itself contains, in its metadata, the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So given commit `H`, Git can use this hash ID to look up commit `G`.  That in turn supplies the hash ID of commit `F`.

Git can, in effect, walk this chain backwards.  That's what `git log` does, normally.  Using `--no-walk` tells `git log`: *show me commits, but do not walk backwards through their chains; show me only the commits I specifically select via the command line.*  So with `--no-walk`, you will see only the commits you selected, and not their ancestry.

Reflogs, like branch names, hold hash IDs.  The reflogs are organized into one log per name (branch name, tag name, and so on) plus one log for the special name `HEAD`.  These are, at least currently, stored in plain files in the `.git/logs` directory.  Each log has entries—one line per file, in this case—and each entry corresponds to the hash ID that the name resolved-to at some earlier time.  You can use these to access the earlier values, so `master@{1}` tells Git to use the one-step-earlier value: before the most recent update to the name `master`, it resolved to some hash ID; now it resolves to some (probably different) hash ID; we want the one from one step back.  The name `master@{2}` tells Git that we want the value from two steps back.

**Note that these are name-update steps, not commit-backwards-arrow steps.**  Sometimes `master@{1}` is the same as `master~1`, `master@{2}` is the same as `master~2`, and so on—but sometimes these are different.  The suffix syntax `master~2` or `master^2` operates with / on the commit graph.  The suffix syntax `master@{number}` operates with / on the reflog for master.

(The current value of the branch name, `master@{0}`, isn't in the `master` reflog because it is in `master` itself.  Updating `master` will take the current value and add it to the log, and then set the new value.)

You can have Git spill out the contents of some or all reflogs using `git reflog`.  If there are no reflogs at all—which will be the case if you remove them all—nothing will come out here as there are no longer any saved values.  However, all the *names* still have their values, and `HEAD` still exists and contains a branch name such as `master`.

#### Even more detail

Note that the way `git log` functions, it can only really show one commit at a time.  To handle this, it uses a [*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  You can, for instance, run:

```
git log <hash1> <hash2> <hash3>
```

using three actual hashes, or:

```
git log master develop feature/tall
```

which uses names to find hash IDs, or:

```
git log master master@{1} master@{2}
```

which uses two reflog entries (plus the branch name) to find hash IDs.

In all cases, Git inserts all the hash IDs into a priority queue.

Using `--reflog` as a command-line argument tells `git log` to take all the values from the reflogs and insert those into the queue.

If nothing goes into the queue, Git inserts the result of resolving `HEAD` to a hash ID instead.

At this point, the queue is presumably not empty, because if nothing else, we got a hash ID by resolving the name `HEAD`.<sup>1</sup>

The `git log` command now enters a loop, which runs until the queue is empty.  This loop works as follows:

- Take the highest priority commit off the queue.
- Use any selection-type arguments supplied to `git log` to decide whether to display this commit.  If so, display the commit.  (For instance, `git log --grep` selects for display commits whose log message contains the given string or pattern.)
- If `--no-walk` is in effect, we're done with this commit.  Otherwise, choose some or all of the parents of this commit to put into the queue, based on the `--first-parent` flag and any History Simplification selected.

(Note that if a commit is now, or ever has been, in the queue, `git log` won't put it back into the queue, so you will not see the same commit twice.  The priority within the queue is affected by `git log`'s sorting options.)

So, with `--reflog`, we give `git log` multiple starting points from the reflog entries, if there are reflogs.  If there *aren't* any reflogs, `git log` uses its standard default: *start with `HEAD`*.

Regardless of whether we used `--reflog` or not, `git log` now walks commits using the parent linkage in the commits themselves.  This does not depend on the arguments we supplied, except of course for `--no-walk`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>If there are no commits at all, or we're on an "unborn branch" created by `git checkout --orphan`, the queue would be empty at this point, but `git log` will have errored out while trying to resolve the name `HEAD`.

<sup>2</sup>Also, with the `-g` or `--walk-reflogs` argument, `git log` will not walk the *commit graph*.  Instead, it walks the reflog entries.

The difference between `--walk-reflogs` and `--reflog` is that with `--walk-reflogs`, the whole priority queue thing is tossed out entirely: Git looks *only* at the reflogs.  This also changes some output formats.  In fact, `git reflog` really just runs `git log -g`.

Comment: re *"`git log HEAD`

which shows the current commit and its ancestors"*; But it doesn't show descendents. **How does `git log --reflog` show descendents when `git reflog`'s output is empty?**

Comment: I expanded the answer a lot, but the TL;DR is: reflogs do not hold commit ancestry; reflogs hold name-update history. It's the *commit graph* that holds commit ancestry. Note, too, that reflog entries eventually expire, after 90 days by default. The graph never expires. A new clone has no reflog history, but has all the graph linkage.

Comment: I'd honestly put the TL;DR version at the top of your answer

Comment: @DaemonPainter: good idea, done.